# Should I fix the formatting if it changes the meaning?

Tags: discussion, edits, markdown, specific-answer, markdown-rendering

I was going to fix a simple typo in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40306146/1244884). In its [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40306146/1) it goes like this:

> If you want to get an array of ints, with values form 1 to 10, from a Stream, there is IntStream at your disposal.

So I wanted to change `form 1 to 10` to `from 1 to 10`. Simple...

However when I edited the answer, I saw this:

[image]

---

As you can see, what should have read as `Stream<Integer>` is shown as just `Stream` due to `<Integer>` being interpreted as HTML (and rejected by the editor) I presume.

If I format things correctly I reveal what the author truly meant. However wouldn't that also invalidate the votes of the public? After such a change, this may or may not be the same answer that people found so useful.

What should I do?

Comment: Asking author to fix it generally preferred approach to any impactful changes to answers... Does the answer in current form make sense ? If yes there may be some ground to leave as is... but generally such fixes that show author's intent are ok and don't need discussion/get unconditional approval in review.

Comment: Personally I'd just add in the backticks. The post is not less correct using `Stream<Integer>` than just using `Stream`. The poster will notice. You can also just post a comment notifying the poster of the missing backticks.

Comment: “Invalidating” votes is never a concern with edits. Users vote whatever revision they encounter.

Comment: Admittedly I'm not a Java expert so I don't know about that. But if in this context it is safe to do so, then I'll probably just do that. Thx @Scratte

Comment: The generic answer to your question is often "no" (in my opinion), but in this specific instance, fixing the formatting isn't invalidating (or even much changing) the meaning, since the edit changes so little.

Comment: But in general, you shouldn't change the formatting if it means changing the meaning.

Comment: Since the answer was unanimously upvoted even in its incorrectly formatted version, I can't imagine you'd be invalidating anyone's votes by fixing it even if that were a concern.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Stack Overflow has always done this (C# type specifiers in `<` `>` being interpreted as HTML tags outside of a code block), and I've always fixed them without hesitation.

It's not about "don't make edits that change how the post is interpreted", it's "don't make edits that change the author's *intent*". The author *intended* for these to show, because they were made part of the question and are not HTML tags - they were just unaware that the text would go missing and didn't proofread their submission very well.

We see other kinds of problems like new users putting "example files" in without a code block, like "Hi, here is my file I'm trying to read, how can I split it into words":

line1
line2
line3

Of course, it looks like a single line file, and the FGITW might recommend `string.Split` on spaces. Had the post been formatted with code blocks:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

...it's a different interpretation. We make edits that change interpretations all the time, but we should always seek to preserve intent.

Experienced users will probably hit the Edit button to see the raw input before they post a "it's supposed to be `Type<X>` not `Type` kind of comment" or if they suspect that the line structure of the example file might be misrepresented, and if inexperienced users make a comment that is invalidated by a subsequent fix, they'll probably come to acquire the relevant experience that they should check before commenting.

If you do make a formatting fix that you feel invalidates anything, or if you feel that the OP would benefit from having it drawn to their attention so they don't make the same mistake again, it can be worth making a comment to that effect.

Comment: @ggorlen indeed, hence the paragraph of the answer that starts "Experienced users will probably hit edit..." - edit being used not as a "edit" initially, but a "see the raw user intent" which then could actually lead to an edit or an advisory comment to the user.. I too am always surprised how people don't seem to stop and think "wait, my post looks so much more garbage than all the questions I've copypasta'd my work out of up to now, how can I make it better?", but it seems a lot of the time they just don't know and seem unwilling to try. Could problems be autodetected/warned, I wonder..

Answer (score 45):

Escape the first `<`

```
Stream\<Integer>
```

Or use backticks

```
`Stream<Integer>`
```

You're not changing the meaning because

1. It's already there, but seen incorrectly as HTML
2. It's in the code block below

Comment: Either way, I don't see this as something you'd get in trouble for if you did fix it

Comment: A related problem that shows up in C code (probably elsewhere too) is when someone puts the first `#include <header.h>` line (it's usually one of those) on the same line as the triple-backquote for the code block.  No error, but the `#include` line doesn't show up until the question is edited.  Yes, it makes the question clearer; sometimes, it negates a comment about a missing header (but it was there in the question; it just wasn't displayed properly because the OP didn't realize the problem).  I fix it — it makes the question a more accurate rendition of what the OP intended.